# Find the smallest possible value of an integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Say a have an integral, like this one

$$\int_{0}^1 (x-a)^2\, dx$$

and asked to find the smallest possible value of it, as **a** varies. How can I do this? Besides, is there a certain rule I can use to solve this type of questions?
I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Note that the value of the integral is a function of $a$. How do you normally find the minimum of a function?

Comment: @md2perpe, by differentiating it once to find when it equals 0 and then again to know when it is greater than 0, am I correct? I've tried doing that, but I got $$1/2$$, whereas the answer is $$1/12$$

Comment: @Ruben, $1/2$ looks like the value of $a$ that minimizes the integral, $1/12$ looks like the value of the integral when $a=1/2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra, oh I get it now, I didn't put it back to the integral, my fault, sorry...

Comment: @Ruben, it's not uncommon to forget what the problem was actually asking for in cases like this.  You can post an answer to your own question if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} (x-a)^2 &= \frac{(x-a)^3}{3} \Bigg \rvert_0^1 \\
&=\frac{(1-a)^3}{3} - \frac{(-a)^3}{3}\\
&=a^2-a+\frac{1}3\\
&=\left(a-\frac 12\right)^2+\frac {1}{12} \ge \frac{1}{12}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d}{da}\int_{0}^{1}(x-a)^2 = 2\int_{0}^{1}(a-x)\,dx $$
equals zero iff $a=\frac{1}{2}$, and such value is clearly associated with an absolute minimum, equal to
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(x-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\,dx\stackrel{\text{Archimedes}}{=}\frac{1}{3}\cdot 1 \cdot\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{12}.$$
You like an overkill? Shifted Legendre polynomials give an orthogonal base of $L_2(0,1)$ with respect to the usual inner product. It follows that the  $L^2$-norm of a polynomial of the form $\alpha P_0(2x-1)+\frac{1}{2}P_1(2x-1)$ attains its minimum at $\alpha=0$ and such minimum equals $\frac{1}{2^2(2\cdot 1+1)}$.
The last approach leads to the uber-generalization
$$ \min_{\deg q < n}\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^n+q(x)\right)^2\,dx = \frac{1}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}^2}.$$

Comment: Archimedes ?? $~~$

Comment: @A---B: it stands for *the determination of the area of the parabolic segment found by Archimedes*.